# VBA find cell of closest value

Tags: vba, find, cell, closest

I have an excel file that looks like:

```
12123    51212
12123.5  45832
12124    37656
12124.5  32987
12125    42445
```

and so on, where column A is always 0.5 increasing and column B has a certain output.

Now I have a specific value in cell E2, say 12124,23 and I want a **VBA** code to return, in this case, that the best matching value is in **cell A3**, because I need this cell location in further code, I don't need the corresponding value in column B. I don't know how to start, however. The file can be up to 30000 rows big.

I'd only like to know first which method to use, then I will try to write the code myself of course :)

JV

Comment: Is it working properly? If it is, please validate the answer with the tick right under the down vote, so that we can close the subject. If it's not we will help you to get it right.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it. I validated two answers that helped me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to use VBA for your problem, Excel will do it perfectly fine!

Try this

```
=vlookup(E2;A:A;2;true)
```

and for what you are trying to do, you HAVE TO sort your A column in an ascending fashion, or else you will get an error!

And if you do need that in VBA,

a simple for+if structure with a test like this

```
    Function pr24(ByVal Value_To_Match As Double) As Range


For i = 2 To ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If Cells(i, 1) > Value_To_Match Then
        If Abs(Cells(i - 1, 1) - Value_To_Match) >= Abs(Cells(i, 1) - Value_To_Match) Then
            pr24 = Range(Cells(i, 1))
        Else
            pr24 = Range(Cells(i - 1, 1))
        End If

        Exit For
    Else

    End If
Next i



End Function
```

or you can use the worksheet function Vlookup

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.VLOOKUP()
```

Comment: I clarified my desciption, i'm looking for a VBA code that returns the cell location containing the nearest value.

Comment: @024pr Did it work? Is your problem solved? If it is please validate an answer to close the subject!

Answer (score 1):

You need to **sort** your data in column A first (smallest to largest), and then you can use a simple lookup formula:

`=LOOKUP(E2,A:A)`

If you don't want to sort the data, then you can use a VBA loop like so - however this is very inefficient - you should always use worksheet formulas where you can:

```
Sub SO()

Dim resultCell      As Excel.Range
Dim checkCell       As Double
Dim bestDiff        As Double

checkCell = Range("E2").Value
bestDiff = checkCell

For i = 1 To Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    If Range("A" & i).Value <= checkCell Then
        If (checkCell - Range("A" & i).Value) < bestDiff Then
            bestDiff = checkCell - Range("A" & i)
            Set resultCell = Range("A" & i)
        End If
    End If
Next i

MsgBox "Best match is in " & resultCell.Address

Set resultCell = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I clarified my desciption, i'm looking for a VBA code that returns the cell location containing the nearest value.

Answer (score 1):

You could use VLOOKUP function for this:-

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.VLOOKUP(lookup_value, table_array, column_index, range_lookup)
```

Set your values as below:-

```
lookup_value = 12124.23
table_array = would be the range Ax:Bx containing your values
column_index = 2 (the second column of table_array)
range_lookup = true
```

Setting range_lookup to true means that if the vlookup doesn't find the exact value it will return the closest match.

Note this will only work if the values in column A are sorted in ascending order.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I clarified my desciption, i'm looking for a VBA code that returns the cell location containing the nearest value.

Answer (score 0):

You dont'need VBA, a call co VLOOKUP Excel function will do the trick; remember to set the last parameter to true, to find a non exact match with the searched value

It should be like something similar to:
= VLOOKUP(E2, A:B, 2, true)

Comment: I clarified my desciption, i'm looking for a VBA code that returns the cell location containing the nearest value.